# React Native - how do I use localization with react-navigation to make translations accessible across screens?

Tags: javascript, react-native, localization, expo, translation

I am trying to use localization to offer multiple language options in an app I am putting together. I am using `react-navigation` to move through different screens and I want to use `expo-localization` to access local language settings. I have looked at the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/localization/) and I'm not sure how to integrate this into my navigation. How would I access Localization.locale in the different screens to be able to display the proper language?:

Below is a sample of the first landing screen and my routing.

**App.js**

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs'
    import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { createStore } from 'redux';
    
    import ourReducer from './store/reducer';
    const store = createStore(ourReducer);
    global.x = 'https://volleybuddy.metis-data.site'
    
    
    import Home from './components/Home'
    import Profile from './components/Profile'
    import Login from './components/Login'
    import SignUp from './components/SignUp'
    import StartScreen from './components/StartScreen'

    //import language settings
    import * as Localization from 'expo-localization'; // or whatever library you want
    import i18n from 'i18n-js'; // or whatever library you want

    const en = {
    login: 'Login'
    };

    const es = {
    login: 'Entre'
    };

    i18n.fallbacks = true;
    i18n.translations = { es, en };

    // This will log 'en' for me, as I'm an English speaker
    console.log(Localization.locale);
    
    export default class App extends Component {
    
    
      render(){
    
        return (
          
          <Provider store={ store }>
            <AppContainer/>
          </Provider>
        );
        }
    }
    
    const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: Home,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              <Ionicons  name="ios-home" size={25} color={tintColor}/>
              // <Icon name="qrcode" size={25} color={tintColor} />
            )
          }
        },
        Profile: {
          screen: Profile,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
              // <Icon name="search" size={25} color={tintColor} />
              <Ionicons  name="md-person" size={25} color={tintColor}/>
            )
          }
        },
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: '#eb6e3d'
        }
      }
    );
    
    const RootSwitch = createSwitchNavigator({ 
      StartScreen,
      SignUp,
      Login,
      bottomTabNavigator
      });
    
    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootSwitch);
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';


class StartScreen extends Component {

    render(){
        <View>
            <Text>{HERE I WOULD BE PASSING VALUES HERE}</Text>
        </View>

    }
}

export default StartScreen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example in App.js make :

```
const en = {
 login: 'Heloooooooo'
};
```

and in StartScreen:

```
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
<View>
  {i18n.t('login')} //output is : Heloooooooo
</View>
```